# Kubernetes Java client: cannot mount an existing configMap to a Pod

Tags: java, kubernetes, configmap

I'm developing a Java application that creates some Kubernetes Jobs using the official Kubernetes Java client. Each Job uses its configuration directory, which already exists as a configMap in the cluster. (This configMap was created using `kubectl create configmap {name} --from-file=/...` )

Using Java client, I successfully created a `V1ConfigMap` object that refers to a specific configMap, and I also found that `V1Volume.setConfigMap()` will convert `V1ConfigMapVolumeSource` to `V1Volume` that can be mounted by a container.

However, I couldn't find the way to map `V1ConfigMap` and `V1ConfigMapVolumeSource`.

Here is my code:

```java
public void setConfigMap(V1ConfigMap cm, String mountPath){
       
    V1ConfigMapVolumeSource volSource = new V1ConfigMapVolumeSource();
        
    //Some additional mappings are needed here.
    //volSource = ...(cm)

    //create V1Volume from V1ConfigMapVolumeSource
    String volName = "appSetting";
    V1Volume settingVol = new V1Volume().name(volName);
    settingVol.setConfigMap(volSource);

    //create V1VolumeMount
    V1VolumeMount volumeMount = new V1VolumeMount();
    volumeMount.setMountPath(mountPath);
    volumeMount.setName(volName);

    //set created objects to the Job
    job.getSpec().getTemplate().getSpec().addVolumesItem(settingVol);
    job.getSpec().getTemplate().getSpec().getContainers().get(0).addVolumeMountsItem(volumeMount);
}
```

Does anyone know the way to solve this, or is my way to approach completely wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated into the [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1ConfigMapVolumeSource.md) for `V1ConfigMapVolumeSource`, there is a `name` parameter (type `String`) which is the [name of the referent](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/#names).

To link a `ConfigMap` inside a `ConfigMapVolumeSource`, just put the name of the `ConfigMap` in the name parameter, that should be enough.